# set theory questions

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I need to prove the following:

Given cardinal numbers $ k_1 ,  k_2,  \lambda _1,  \lambda_2$

such that $ k_1 \leq k_2 $ and $ \lambda_1 \leq \lambda_2$

Prove

$k_1 + \lambda_1 \leq k_2 + \lambda_2$

I took the definition from my book that said $k + \lambda = |A \cup B| $ where $A$ and $B$ are sets such that $|A|=k$, $|B|=\lambda$ and $A\cap B=\emptyset$

and figured I would have to prove :

Given sets $A$ , $B$, $C$ , $D$

Prove:

a) $A \subseteq A\cup B$

b) if $A \subseteq C$ and $B \subseteq D$ 
   then $A \cup B \subseteq C \cup D$

Comment: By $\le$ do you mean $\subset$?

Comment: Are you using $\leq$ for "subset of"? Also, what have you tried? This is just a matter of applying definitions.

Comment: You should edit to reflect the suggested changes if you think they are applicable.

Comment: this is a homework question you must show what you have tried .

Comment: Doesn't the definition in your book also require $A\cap B=\emptyset$, i.e., the sets have to be disjoint. Also you should have $|A|=k$ and $|B|=\lambda$. (Otherwise the difinition you quoted does not make much sense.)

Answer (score 3):

"A is a subset of B": $A\subseteq B$, formatted $A \subseteq B$.

> $(a)$ $A \subseteq A\cup B$.

This means that if $x \in A$, then $x \in A$ OR $x\in B$. This is necessarily true. Every element that's in $A$ is also in the union of $A$ and $B$, since the union of two sets $A, B$ contains all elements that are in $A$, together with all elements that are in $B$.

> $(b)$ If $A\subseteq C$ and $B\subseteq D$, then $A\cup B \subseteq C\cup D$.

If $x \in A$, then by the definition of $A\subseteq C$, $x \in C$. Likewise, if $x \in B$, then $x \in D$, for the same reason, since $B \subseteq D$. So if $A \subseteq C$ and $B\subseteq D$, then $x \in A \cup B$ means $x \in A$ or $x \in B$. But we've seen that this means $x \in C$ or $x \in D$, that is, we have that $x \in C\cup D$.

Comment: This needs a TU! +1